# difference between drill down, drill up and drill across in microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

Good afternoon. Please tell me this question: 
What is the difference of different levels Drill Map in Microstrategy? (UP, DOWN, ACROSS) 
Particularly interested in ACROSS. What is it used? The manual says that this is the same as UP ... But then I do not believe it. 
Thanks in advance for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Drill Accross gives you an option to drill into different hierarchy. So Up or Down oparates within the same hierarchy, and ACROSS lets you go out of it.

Comment: Alex - is the answer satisfactory ?

Comment: Alex - please note that if some answer is satisfactory and you will mark it as satisfactory you will gain the Reputation points for the marking you made.

Answer (score 1):

Drill across is used in MicroStrategy to jump from a Hierarchy to another.

If you are not familiar with MicroStrategy terminology, you can think of an hierarchy like a dimension, i.e. from day to year, but you can also create custom hierarchies not caring of the parent-child relationships.

A non-parent/child based hierarchy can be useful when you need to analyze sales to a specific customer and then get to product categories, sub-categories and items. So you can create an hierarchy like:

```
Region -> Customer -> Category -> Sub-Category -> Item
```

If you follow this path you are still drill `UP` and `DOWN` in this hierarchy defined by you or another developer.

Drill `ACROSS` adds an additional level of freedom for the users (if you allow them to do it), so they can decide to go from Customer to Week to get the weekly sales for that customer, even if the developers didn't provide that path.

It's a functionality for experienced users (they should know what are they doing) which leverages the dimensional model behind the MicroStrategy schema.